# Find the smallest number of composite integers so that at least one pair will no be coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest number of composite integers, each $\le$ 528, so that no matter how we choose them at least one pair will not be coprime.

p.s It is not an exam question. It just seem interesting and I had no clue of how to correctly approach it.

Comment: Why don't you just choose a single pair of non-coprime integers??? For example, choose $8$ and $10$, and your done ($2$ numbers).

Comment: But it seems so simple. I thought about just choosing two but.. @barakmanos

Comment: "no matter how we choose them" - my mistake.

Comment: @barakmanos:  I was reading the question to be the smallest number such that any set of composites of that cardinality has at least one non-coprime pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redone answer:  Let us do it for composites up to $N$.  The minimum number of composites one must select to guarantee that at least one pair is not coprime is one more than the number of primes less than or equal to $\sqrt N$.  This is because every composite less than or equal to $N$ has at least one factor less than or equal to $\sqrt N$.  We can show this is minimal by constructing a set of size the number of primes less than or equal to $\sqrt N$, in particular the set of squares of these primes.  For $N=528$, there are eight primes less than $\sqrt {528}$ and our pairwise coprime set is $\{4,9,25,49,121,169,180,361\}$

Comment: Are you assuming a different question? Because the smallest number of composite integers, such that **at least one pair is not coprime** is simply $2$.

Comment: @barakmanos It says "no matter how we choose them."

Comment: @MattSamuel: Right!!! Thanks.